# Accessing Jenkins API using Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jenkins, jenkins-api

As titled,

I tried to access the Jenkins API (Jenkins latest version, which is 2.204.1) using the [Jenkins library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jenkins). I tried to make a call to retrieve the build log using the following code in React

```
import Jenkins from 'jenkins'

// ngrok is used to expose Jenkins's URL to the internet, so that Github webhooks can connect properly to the Jenkins.
const jenkinsConfig = {
    baseUrl : 'http://username:password@URLToMyJenkins.ngrok.io', 
    crumbIssuer: true
};
const _jenkins = Jenkins(jenkinsConfig);

useEffect(() => {
    const getBuildLog = () => {
        runner.build.get({
                name: 'jobname',
                number: 1
            }, (err, data) => {
            if (err){
                console.log('Its on err!!! ::: ', err);
            } 

            console.log('Can i see what is the data ::: ', data);
        });
    }
}, []);
```

When i run the above code, it throws me the CORS error, but on the ngrok console, i can see that the API was successfully called (status 200)

```
OPTIONS /job/GHTest2/1/api/json                                           200 OK
```

On the web console

```
Access to fetch at 'http://URLToMyJenkins.ngrok.io/job/GHTest2/1/api/json' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I installed Jenkins CORS-Filter-Plugin, and put the following configs onto it

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origins - http://localhost:3000, http://URLToMyJenkins.ngrok.io
Access-Control-Allow-Methods - GET, PUT, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers - origin, Content-Type, X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Expose-Headers - origin, *
Access-Control-Max-Age - 999
```

And even disable the security and CSRF protection in Jenkins, still didnt work and keep hitting the CORS error.

Did i do anything wrong here, or Jenkins API simply is not accessible from the frontend side using Javascript?

Comment: Check the response your browser received, does it response with the correct `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header?

Comment: @ZmenHu on network tab on the inspector, the response tab is empty. On the headers tab, it shows that the request was successfully (200).

Comment: So does the headers tab contains a header called `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` ? The header is required to pass the CORS mechanism. You can check it here [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve this by setting the following on Jenkins's CORS configuration

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers - Authorization
```

With that, all the codes above finally can work as expected.